# Generic Extended React Component Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im looking to extend the React Component class with my own class.

```
export class ReactComponent<P,S> extends React.Component<P,S> {
    public doStuff() {
        alert("Custom React Component");
    }
}

export class MyComponent extends ReactComponent<MyProps, any> {
    render() {
        return <div onLoad={this.doStuff()}></div>;
    }
}
```

This appears to compile but throws the following error on load.

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Using React 15.3, I must be missing something.

Comment: Just a guess, but I'm pretty sure that you need to pass the function to `onLoad` and not the result of function execution. Something like: `onLoad={ this.doStuff.bind(this) }`

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend this pattern. tracking super calls is frustrating and you can achieve all of the same functionality by simply wrapping components not extending them (or making a higher order component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Most likely an ordering issue. Make sure that the javascript is loaded in the right order.

## More

- try not to use outfile : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html
- I've inherited from `React.Component` before and it works fine e.g. https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/6dd26dd9f2c7144d89d653fea8129b5b55c3888c/src/app/ui.tsx#L10

Comment: Was testing internal to the file i was working on for brevity.  Moved the class to a file path above and called an import and everything works.